# Gulp bundling issue for Udemy Wordpress course

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, webpack, gulp

I've been coding along to Udemy's WordPress developer course and hit an issue with getting different parts of the folder to bundle when running `gulp watch` - I wanted to ignore it but it seems like the course is going to be working with these modules going forward, so I think I'm stuck until I figure it out.

Changes to the CSS and JS modules are supposed to appear in the localhost, but not only do the modules not work, direct changes to the folder's style.css file aren't registering without refreshing the page either. Gulp is only automating changes to the .php files. I followed along with the courses placement of the necessary files and settings.js file, but it's still not working

The way it's currently set up:

- using Local by Flywheel
- gulpfile.js, settings.js, package.json, and webpack.config.js in the "fictional-university/app/public" folder, same as where the "wp-content folder" lives
- settings.js set to:

```
     exports.themeLocation = './wp-content/themes/fictional-university-theme/';
    exports.urlToPreview = 'http://fictional-university.local/';
```

- a gulpfile.js that looks like this:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    settings = require('./settings'),
    webpack = require('webpack'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    rgba = require('postcss-hexrgba'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    cssvars = require('postcss-simple-vars'),
    nested = require('postcss-nested'),
    cssImport = require('postcss-import'),
    mixins = require('postcss-mixins'),
    colorFunctions = require('postcss-color-function');

    gulp.task('styles', function() {
      return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'css/style.css')
        .pipe(postcss([cssImport, mixins, cssvars, nested, rgba, colorFunctions, autoprefixer]))
        .on('error', (error) => console.log(error.toString()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(settings.themeLocation));
    });

    gulp.task('scripts', function(callback) {
      webpack(require('./webpack.config.js'), function(err, stats) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.toString());
        }

        console.log(stats.toString());
        callback();
      });
    });

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
      browserSync.init({
        notify: false,
        proxy: settings.urlToPreview,
        ghostMode: false
      });

       gulp.watch('./**/*.php', function() {
         browserSync.reload();
         done();
      });
      gulp.watch(settings.themeLocation + 'css/**/*.css', gulp.parallel('waitForStyles'));
      gulp.watch([settings.themeLocation + 'js/modules/*.js', settings.themeLocation + 'js/scripts.js'], gulp.parallel('waitForScripts'));
    });

    gulp.task('waitForStyles', gulp.series('styles', function() {
      return gulp.src(settings.themeLocation + 'style.css')
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }))

    gulp.task('waitForScripts', gulp.series('scripts', function(cb) {
      browserSync.reload();
      cb()
    }))
```

- running `gulp watch` in the public folder

The course addressed this in one of their updates, but it hasn't worked for me and a few other users and I haven't gotten any other feedback from students.

Let me know if anyone has any ideas (just fyi, I'm at a very novice level, so it might take some ELI5 sort of guidance)

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem and after few days I found a 'solution'.

Create a new theme using files that are inside 054 49-end.zip (end of lesson 13.)
You will be missing some of the files/folders (images,css folder...) - just add them from your developing project.

Now run gulp watch and continue with lesson. I know this you either found solution or did not continue with course since one year passed from asking question but I hope other people will find this useful.